# Convert in to float CL

Tags: recursion, common-lisp

I want to define a function, which converts the elements of a list in to float.

Thats's my solution, which does not work:

```
(defun intofloat (list)
  (cond 
   ((null liste) nil)
   ((equal (first list) 'id)
    (float (first list)))
   (t (intofloat (rest list)))))
```

Maybe there is someone who could help me!

Thanks!

Comment: If this is homework, are you allowed to use `mapcar`? Please also explain what this part should do and why did you include it in your solution: `(equal (first list) 'id)`.

Comment: I have to define an ite function, so I think I am not allowed to use `mapcar`. 

I include `(equal (first list) 'id)` because just elements from type integer should be convert into float.

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to use `mapcar`, this is truly trivial.

```
* (mapcar #'float '(1 2 3))

(1.0 2.0 3.0)
```

If you are not allowed to use `mapcar`, then you should break your problem down and redefine that function first.

```
(defun my-map (f lst)
  (if (null lst)
      nil
      (let ((hd (car lst))
            (tl (cdr lst)))
        (cons (funcall f hd) (my-map f tl)))))
```